# static vs namespace anónimo

Tags: c++

En C++ disponemos de dos mecanismos similares para limitar el ámbito de aplicación de una variable al fichero de código actual (no cabecera):

```
//fichero.cpp

// opción 1
static std::string Mensaje = "algo"; 

// opción 2
namespace
{
  std::string Mensaje = "algo";
}
```

¿Hay alguna diferencia entre ambas opciones?, ¿cuál se debería usar?, ¿por qué?

Comment: Hay muy buenas discusiones de este tema en SOingles [aquí](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/154469/unnamed-anonymous-namespaces-vs-static-functions) y también [aquí](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4726570/deprecation-of-the-static-keyword-no-more). Quizá sea buena idea recopilar y traducir las respuestas mas relevantes.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Hoy, **para el ejemplo que mencionas** (esto es, para un caso en el que `static` no se usa para declarar variables miembro, y descartando su uso al declarar o implementar clases o funciones), sirven para hacer exactamente lo mismo, que es limitar el uso de esas variables sólo del archivo en el cual se declaran.

En algún momento el comité de `C++` optó por desaprobar ("deprecate") el uso de `static`, quedando el uso de `namespaces` sin nombre como única opción oficialmente aceptada como buena práctica. Este [ya no es el caso](https://stackoverflow.com/a/154482/2550349), y ahora ambos sirven para lo mismo y son aceptados. La razón fue que simplemente [sería difícil concebir que este uso de `static` fuera removido de `C++`](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/cwg_defects.html#1012), especialmente considerando una de sus metas es la compatibilidad con `C`.

Ahora... la diferencia más obvia es que con el uso del `namespace` te ahorras estar escribiendo `static` para cada variable. Se podría decir que es más acorde a la filosofía de `C++`.

Al final la decisión es tuya, pero te agrego otras observaciones que te pueden ayudar:

- Por una parte, usar `static` podría llegar a ser más conocido para otras personas que lean el código, en especial si dichas personas saben `C`, pero no `C++`.
- Por otra parte, la palabra `static` tiene otros usos y esto prodría llegar a ser confuso. Por ejemplo, su uso dentro de una función, donde cualquier variable declarada con esta palabra se inicializará una sola vez en todo el programa, y su valor persistirá entre llamadas de funciones; esto es, si inicializas la variable con 0, pero al final de la función el valor de la variable `static` es 1, cuando vuelvas a llamar la función el valor de esa variable será 1, no 0. Si quieres evitar problemas con esto, considera usar `namespace`, pero esto también puede tener sus problemas con otros usos de la palabra `namespace` y crear confusión a los lectores de tu código.

Personalmente, usaría `static`, porque primero aprendí `C` y nunca me acuerdo de usar `namespace` de esa manera.

Comment: He borrado los comentarios de esta respuesta porque se estaban convirtiendo en una discusión que no llevaba a ninguna parte. @eferion, si esa respuesta tiene sentido y es útil *en el contexto de la pregunta tal como está formulada*, por favor acéptala.